# JavaScript / Python interaction in Linux without a REST framework?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, linux, apache

I'm working on some changes to a page that needs to retrieve information from some files under **/proc** so the page can display version information to the user. Currently, the page is generated entirely by the Python script, which allows me to just read the file and put everything in the page at creation time.

However, this led to the issue that the version numbers wouldn't update when a new version of the software was uploaded. I don't want to regenerate the page every time a new package is installed, so I made the main page static and want to instead just query the information from a Python script and return it to the page to populate the page when loaded.

The Python scripts are set up as CGI and have sudo access, so there's no issue with them retrieving those files. However, if I wanted to use something like AJAX to call the Python script, is there any way I could return the data without using a REST framework such as Flask or Django? The application needs to be lightweight and preferably not rely on a new framework.

Is there a way I can do this with vanilla JavaScript and Python?

Comment: But you can use CGI-provided services via ajax too; it's all just HTTP requests

Comment: @Pointy I'm aware that I can make an AJAX request to run the script, my question is how I send the data read from the files to the JavaScript callback function using vanilla JavaScript and Python.

Comment: ?? The same way you'd send back a response to any other HTTP request. You probably would not send back HTML of course, but it's just output from the CGI script that's available as the response text to JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: @Pointy And that would be how? Every result I've found from Googling is that you need a REST framework to respond.

Comment: How do you respond from the CGI script currently? A web server plus CGI scripts basically *is* a framework, albeit a simple one. The term "REST" gets thrown around all the time but it doesn't really mean anything in particular.

Comment: @Pointy I don't... that's my whole point. The script as it is now creates the page from scratch and then redirects to the created page. As I said, I'm now instead using a static HTML page and need to know how to use vanilla Python to send data back to the AJAX callback function.

Comment: Generally with CGI your script can simply write whatever it wants to standard output. That gets sent as the response. You could do that now instead of using a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was fairly simple, I just made a few syntactical errors that led to it not working the first few times I tried it.

So the request looked like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200)) {
            var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            // Do stuff with the JSON here...
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", scriptURL, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

From there, the Python script simply needed to do something like this to return JSON data containing my version numbers:

```
import sys, cgi, json
result = {}
result['success'] = True
result['message'] = "The command completed successfully"
d = {}
... write version information to the 'd' map ...
result['data'] = d
sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n")
sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result))
sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.close()
```

The most persistent problem that took me forever to find was I forgot a closing quotation in my script tag, which caused the whole page to not load.